# multi_match with type phrase_prefix not working for Date/Number/Integer field

Tags: elasticsearch, rest-client

everyone , I am working on upgrading the elastic search server from version 6.6.x to 6.8.22 , and then found some of query is not working in the 6.8.22 for Date/Number/Integer field

this is the code in the java

```
   final MultiMatchQueryBuilder multiMatchQueryBuidler = 
   QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(searchFor);
   multiMatchQueryBuidler.operator(Operator.AND);
   multiMatchQueryBuidler.type(Type.PHRASE_PREFIX);
```

this is the query in the elastic search

```json
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "8888.999",
      "fields": [],
      "type": "phrase_prefix",
      "operator": "AND",
      "slop": 0,
      "prefix_length": 0,
      "max_expansions": 50,
      "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
      "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
      "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

is there someone knows the reason ? if I remove the "type":"phrase_prefix" , then it could search the result

Comment: Please give us some documents you are working on so we can easily repeat your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It might be [this change](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/37436/files) or one of the Lucene version updates but what matters is that full *text* queries (like `match_phrase`) don't really make sense for *numeric* fields so you should figure out your data schema anyway.

Comment: thanks for your answer , I check the change MappedFieldType.java , and is that means it only can search out the text field type ?  `public Query phrasePrefixQuery(TokenStream stream, int slop, int maxExpansions) throws IOException {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only use phrase prefix queries on text fields - not on [" + name
            + "] which is of type [" + typeName() + "]");
    }`

Comment: Yes, Phrase queries should only be run against text fields.